# Add a node part with a TikZ style

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to define a TikZ node style that sets the node shape to `rectangle split` and automatically adds a first part with content defined by the style. The usual node text appears in the second part. Is there a way to do this, or something similar to this?

##### Desired behavior

Code:

```
\node[achtung] at (1, 2) {Falling rocks};
```

Output:

```
( Achtung | Falling rocks )
```

##### Attempts

I've tried

```
achtung/.append style={
  execute at begin node={Achtung\nodepart{two}},
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split horizontal,
  rectangle split parts=2
}
```

and more sophisticated versions, like

```
achtung/.append style={
  execute at begin node={Achtung\protect\nodepart{two}\protect\begingroup},
  execute at end node={\protect\endgroup},
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split horizontal,
  rectangle split parts=2,
  every one node part/.style={
    execute at begin node={},
    execute at end node={}
  },
  every two node part/.style={
    execute at begin node={},
    execute at end node={}
  }
}
```

They all lead to an `"Extra }, or forgotten \\endgroup.\n\\pgfutil@reserved@c ->\\egroup \n"` error.

Versions using `\pgfnodeparttwobox` compile, but don't give the desired behavior.

#### Minimal not-working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
  achtung/.append style={
    execute at begin node={Achtung\nodepart{two}}, % remove this line to compile successfully
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    draw
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[achtung] {Falling rocks};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you please embed one of your styles in a short MWE, which compiles? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO: Sure. Done.

Comment: Would a syntax like `\node[achtung={Falling rocks}];` be acceptable?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.—Yes, but I'd like to allow `\node[achtung=...] at (1, 2) ...;`, which I don't think is possible if you use `node contents` to insert the desired text.

Comment: Yes, that might be a drawback ..

Comment: You can't use \node as it is too important to modify, but you could define another macro to be expanded as \node with the proper arguments.

Comment: @Torbjørn T., maybe `node contents` is the best option for now, since I can just move the options block to the end: `\node at (1, 2) [achtung={Falling rocks}];` It would be nice to apply this style without having to remember that it breaks the usual node syntax, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook `execute at begin node` is simply too early to play around with nodeparts. There really is no appropriate hook to use here. We could try to misuse one of the other macros that will be executed right at the start – they deal with horizontal alignments and nested TikZ pictures (?) – …

But instead of messing around with them and creating incompatibilities I'll just add our own hook `print at begin node` which acts similar to `node contents` but instead of replaces it simply prefixes what comes between `{` and `}`.

(This hook will *not* be reset for when a TikZ picture is part of the node content but it's rarely a good idea to do that in the first place.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn \makeatletter
\tl_replace_once:Nnn \tikz@do@fig
  { \ignorespaces }
  { \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/print~at~begin~node} \ignorespaces }
\makeatother \ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/print at begin node}{}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
  achtung/.append style={
    print at begin node = Achtung \nodepart{two},
    rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, draw}}
\tikzset{
  gnutcha/.append style={
    print at begin node = \nodepart{two} Achtung \nodepart{one},
    rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, draw}}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node[achtung]            {Falling rocks}
       node[gnutcha] at (0, -1) {Falling rocks};

\tikz \node[achtung]            {Falling rocks \nodepart{text} You're not the }
       node[achtung] at (0, -1) {Falling rocks \nodepart{one}    boss of me.  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `\ignorespaces` is irrelevant in this use case because we always end the new hook with `\nodepart{…}` which has its own `\ignorespaces` (and is basically `\tikz@do@fig` for nodeparts). Since PGFKeys also strips its values of spaces, the explicit spaces`\space` or ``\ `` might be helpful. Since [TikZ is bugged when it comes to nodeparts and ends](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1155) I'm not even attempting a `print at end node` hook.

Comment: Whoa, I never knew you could [reach into existing commands](https://www.texdev.net/2012/01/22/programming-latex3-more-on-token-list-variables/) like this! I've seen so many suggestions to adjust a command by copying its source code with some small change, and I've always wondered if there was a better way. Here, are you taking advantage of the coincidence that the first `\ignorespaces` in `\tikz@do@fig` happens to come right before the node content?

Comment: @Vectornaut Yes, I've also taken advantage that `\tikz@do@fig` doesn't take an argument, otherwise `etoolbox`, other patching package or other tricks would be necessary. We could've also used `\tl_put_right:Nn` leaving an extra `\ignorespaces` in it because it is also at the end of `\tikz@do@fig`'s definition.

Answer (score 2):

Using `node contents` you could have `node contents={Achtung\nodepart{two}#1}` in the style, and use it as `achtung={Falling rocks}`. As noted in comments using `node contents` means you can't do`\node [..] at (x,y)...`, though `\node at (x,y) [...]` does work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
  achtung/.append style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    draw,
    node contents={Achtung\nodepart{two}#1}
  },
  achtung/.default=
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[achtung={Falling rocks}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output image: [Achtung | Falling rocks]]

Comment: This is the method I've gone with for now, but I'm keeping the question open in case someone finds a way to allow more typical-looking node syntax.

Answer (score 1):

With a command ?

EDIT: with the Alan Munn' comment
By adding the position of the node as a parameter and the `D(){}` specification for the #2 parameter

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mynode}{ O{achtung} d() m }{
\IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\path node[#1,right]{#1\nodepart{two}#3};}
    {\path (#2) node[#1,right]{#1\nodepart{two}#3};}
}
\tikzset{
    achtung/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        draw,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines](0,0)grid(3,2);
\mynode[achtung] (2,1) {Falling rocks}
\mynode (0,0) {achtung is the default style}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that this is likely the most robust solution, but the OP wants to allow the `\node[] at (x,y) {}` syntax, which your command doesn't support.

Comment: @Alan Munn, I modified my answer, indeed it was not enough.

Comment: Suggestion: if you change the specification of the #2 argument to `D(){}` instead of `m`, you can use closer to the expected `\node` syntax with your command, `\mynode[achtung] (x,y) {...}` only missing the `at`.

Comment: @Alan Munn I didn't know about this possibility, but in the `interface3` documentation p.3, I read "The D stands for Do not use." I don't know why this feature is deprecated.

Comment: You're reading this wrong. The `D` described in `interface3` is the argument specifier in an Expl3 function, e.g. `\foo:D`. It is not the delimited argument specifier of the `xparse` `\NewDocumentCommand` specification. That `D` (the one I'm using) allows you to specify a delimited optional argument. So using `D(){}` is not using a deprecated functionality. This is an unfortunate overlapping of distinct uses.

Comment: The `D` argument I'm using is described in `usrguide` p.3.

Comment: @Alan Munn Sorry for my mistake, I'm taking advantage of this opportunity and including it in my answer.

Comment: I'd rather use the `d()` argument specifier, and then use `\IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}`  (or use a required argument in parentheses) instead of `D(){}`, because if you omit the argument you'd get an error.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to fix my bad suggestion with @Skillmon's superior one.